# Getting textarea result failure using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Hi everybody can you please find the correct result for this textbox result, and what i made mistake

```
<div class='save'>
    <input type='button' class='comment' value='Save' id='12'/>
</div>
<textarea class='field' id='12'></textarea>
```

```js
$('.save').on('click',function(){
    var id = $('.comment').attr('id');
    var text_id = $('textarea.field').attr('id');
    var comments = $('textarea#'+text_id).val();
    alert(comments);
});
```

Output: undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ID must be unique. You have id="12" two times. jQuery won't know thich on will be the text and which one will be the button.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute id is same for both input and textarea tags which is wrong. According to HTML standards id should be unique throughout the document.

Try changing the id of textarea.